# How to get the selected record id (jsf 'h' datatable) from database in EJB and JSF

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jsf-2

I am new to `JAVA/JSF`, i am trying to perform `CRUD` Operations on `db` records.

i have successfully shown all records in `jsf` `h` tag `datatable`. i have also created the edit `CommandButton`, by clicking, it will make the   fields editable, after editing i will able to save the changes. i have created two projects in `myEclipse`, one is for database `EJB 2.0` and other is `JSF` project.

i have done this so far

`EJB 2.0` side project code

```
public void saveUser(int id, String fname, String lname) {
    String query = "UPDATE user SET id='"+id+"',fname='"+fname+"',lname='"+lname+"' where id = " + id;
    int outcome =entitymanager.createNativeQuery(query).executeUpdate();
            }
```

this is a function to update user written in `EJB` side

i have other `JSF` project which have `managedBean` and `xhtml` Class

userView.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<h:head>
    <title>JSF 2.x Page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="enter,your,keywords,here" />
    <meta http-equiv="description"
        content="A short description of this page." />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">-->
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>

        <h:dataTable var="item" value="#{first.list}" styleClass="order-table"
            headerClass="order-table-header"
            rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row">

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>

                <h:inputText value="#{item.id}" size="15"
                    rendered="#{item.editable}" />
                <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"  rendered="#{!item.editable}"></h:outputText>
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">First Name</f:facet>

                <h:inputText value="#{item.fname}" size="15"
                    rendered="#{item.editable}" />
                <h:outputText value="#{item.fname}" rendered="#{!item.editable}"></h:outputText>
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Last Name</f:facet>

                <h:inputText value="#{item.lname}" size="15"
                    rendered="#{item.editable}" />
                <h:outputText value="#{item.lname}" rendered="#{!item.editable}"></h:outputText>

            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>

                <h:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{first.editUser}"
                    rendered="#{!item.editable}" >

                </h:commandButton>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
        <br />
        <h:commandButton value="Save Changes" action="#{first.saveAction}" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <p>
            First Name:
            <h:inputText value="#{first.fname}"></h:inputText>
            <br /> Last Name:
            <h:inputText value="#{first.lname}"></h:inputText>
            <br /> <br />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <h:commandButton value="Insert" action="#{first.add}" />

            <br />
            <h:messages id="test"></h:messages>
        </p>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and this is `managedBean First.java`

```
package jsfpckg;

import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import model.User;

import jsfejb.sbeanRemote;

@ManagedBean(name = "first")
@ViewScoped
public class First {



    @EJB(mappedName = "ejb:/ejb/sbean!jsfejb.sbeanRemote")
    sbeanRemote data;

    private List<User> list;
    private String fname;
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    private String lname;

    public void setList(List<User> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List<User> getList() {

        list = data.retriveDatatypes();
        System.out.println("list in first class is" + list);
        return list;

    }

    public String editAction(User user) {

        user.setEditable(true);
        return null;
    }


    public String saveAction(){

        list=data.retriveDatatypes();
        for(User user:list){
            user.setEditable(false);                
        }
        //User user = null;
        return null;
    }

    public void add() {

        data.insertUser(fname, lname);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(" Succesfully added to database ",
                new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage("Successful"));
        // return "output";
    }

    public void editUser(){

        //getRowIndex();

        data.saveUser(id, fname, lname);

    }
}
```

and this is `bean` class

User.java

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the user database table.
 * 
 */

public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private int id;


    private String fname;


    private String lname;

    public boolean isEditable() {
        return editable;
    }

    public void setEditable(boolean editable) {
        this.editable = editable;
    }

    boolean editable;

    public User() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return this.fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return this.lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

}
```

the problem is whenever i click edit button it does not make it editable

this is how my datatable looks like

[image]

Comment: Take a step back. Try to achieve somethig becoming editable  without a datatable

Comment: And btw, your title talks about getting the id in the right place, but the content talks about the fields not becomming editable... Try to look at them as two separate issues.

Comment: Your edit button should at least change the value of item.editable because your `rendered` expressions look at this value. So you have to pass the item to the action function. I.e. `<h:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{first.editUser(item)}"...`

Comment: i have also tried that `action=#{first.editUser(item)}` earlier, but the thing was not working

Comment: Not working... The action function of the edit buttons doesn't change editable. So nothing will change in your page update. The action function of the edit buttons calls saveUser(), this should do the save button. saveUser(id, fname, lname) will use i.e. fname of your bean, which is only used for new entries (addUser). saveUser must be called with items of the user-class. saveAction doesn't save anything but reads the user list again.

Comment: now i have changed my edit button action to this

Comment: public String editAction(User user){

     System.out.println("in action");
            user.setEditable(true); 
            
            if(user.isEditable()==true){
             
             System.out.println("true");
            }
            else
             System.out.println("false");
            
            return null;
    }

Comment: on xhtml side   <h:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{first.editAction(item)}" rendered="#{!item.editable}">

                </h:commandButton> but it doesnt worked

Comment: "Doesn't work" is no diagnostic feedback. You have to give more information what's happening or not happening. You can set a breakpoint in the first line of editAction() to test if it's called and to look at the parameter (user).